# Is it possible that only a finite number of axioms among axiom schemata of ZFC is consistent?

Tags: set-theory

I was reading a wonderful argument of Hamkins in https://mathoverflow.net/a/51786 , saying that even a model $M$ of ZFC where $\neg CON(ZFC)$ holds has a "pseudo-model" $m$ within it which satisfies all axioms of ZFC, because $M$ has more axioms (coming from axiom schemata) than the axioms of ZFC.

Is it possible, then, that our metatheory is itself in this situation, in the sense that the ZFC (as applied to our metatheory) in itself inconsistent, but only a (huge but) finite number of axioms (coming from axiom schemata) of ZFC is consistent?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "ZFC (as applied to our meta theory)". But the following situation is certainly possible: ZFC is inconsistent, but the fragment of ZFC obtained by restricting to instances of the schemas of length at most the number of atoms in the universe is consistent.

Comment: @Alex: Presumably the meaning is that if $M$ is a model of $\sf ZFC+\lnot\operatorname{Con}(ZFC)$, then in $M$ a large enough fragment of $\sf ZFC$ is consistent, in particularly, one that is large enough to include all the "real axioms" from the meta theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible (at least as long as Zermelo set theory or some other similar base theory is consistent).

But unfortunately it's not for a very interesting reason: There are infinitely many formulas $\phi$ for which the corresponding instance of the replacement axiom schema

$$\forall u \forall p_1, \dots, p_n \big[ (\forall x\in u)(
\exists ! y\; \phi(x, u, p_1, \dots, p_n)\Rightarrow \dots \big]$$

is vacuously true because the antecedent in the implication is provably false for all non-empty $u$ and for all values of $p_1,\dots,p_n.$  (For example, one could take $\phi$ to be $x\ne x,\; x \ne x\wedge x \ne x,\; x \ne x\wedge x\ne x\wedge x\ne x,\;$ etc.)  Excluding $u=\emptyset$ here is fine since in that case the axiom schema is trivially true anyway.

So $V_{\omega+\omega}$ is a model of ZC plus infinitely many instances of the replacement axiom.

---

A more interesting similar question might be: Is there a recursively enumerable axiomatization $T$ in the language of set theory which is provably equivalent to ZFC but in which there are no redundant axioms? (A redundant axiom would be one which can be proven from the *other* axioms of $T$.)  (For this question, assume the consistency of ZFC so that the question has some substance.)

For this revised question, I think we can change the replacement axiom schema, as follows.  For each $m\lt\omega,$ let $\sigma_m$ be universal for $\Sigma_m$ formulas with three free variables.  Then, for each $m\lt\omega,$ we have the single axiom
$$(\forall k\lt\omega)\big(\text{traditional replacement axiom schema for  }\phi(x,u,p) = \sigma_m(k, x,u,p)\big).$$

I haven't checked through all the details here; in particular, you'd need to be sure that you can prove the traditional replacement axiom instances where $\phi$ has more parameters, but that should work by coding $p_1, \dots, p_n$ in a single parameter via Kuratowski pairing.  (You’d also need to be sure that you include enough axioms to prove the necessary properties of $\Sigma_m\text{-universal}$ sets, etc.)

If this all goes as expected, then this revised (but equivalent) version of ZFC would satisfy OP's requested property: it's possible that only finitely many of these new axioms are consistent.

Comment: Presumably, the right way to understand this question is by treating the Replacement schema as simply a list of $\Sigma_n$-truth predicates.

Comment: Yes, that was my first inclination, but it's not really what the OP asked.  And it led to the question of a non-redundant axiomatization of ZF, which I thought might be interesting.  (Someone may have answered that in the literature already -- I don't know.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I added in an outline of what I was thinking of for the non-redundant axiomatization, which uses the analysis via the $\Sigma_n$ hierarchy.

Comment: Nice answer. I'm not sure that when the OP wrote "only a finite number of axioms of ZFC is consistent", they meant "no infinite set of axioms of ZFC is consistent"... but your interpretation is reasonable. Maybe the OP can clarify.

Comment: @AlexKruckman  When I first skimmed it, that's what I assumed OP meant, but it's not what OP actually wrote.  And interpreting this way actually yields a question that I hadn't seen before, whereas there must already be answers posted for the first interpretation.

Comment: Thank you very much for making precise what I wanted to ask, and then answering it. How likely do you think it is actually the case that only a finite number of axioms in the new formulation is consistent? If so, how much of mathematics would be affected? Should I ask it as a separate question?

Comment: @Yuji  Personally I think ZFC is consistent (even with various large cardinal axioms), but nobody really knows -- arguably this is unknowable unless ZFC actually is inconsistent.  I also have no idea how mathematicians would react, if say, the replacement axiom for $\Sigma_{200}$ formulas were shown to be inconsistent; this likely wouldn't affect any known results outside of set theory, but people would probably start to rethink foundations considerably.

Comment: @Yuji  As for posting another question, feel free to try.  You may find that it gets closed as "opinion-based", however.  (I won't vote to close, but it's not clear whether there really can be anything beyond speculation on this, and philosophical discussion isn't well-suited to the StackExchange format.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight!